# Work around for NEST not supporting pattern replace char filter

Tags: nest

NEST doesn't appear to support the `pattern replace char filter` described here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html

I've created an issue at https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/543.

Most of my indexing is working so I would like to continue to use NEST. Is there a way I can work around this using some manual json injection at some point during the index configuration? I'm new to NEST so not sure if this is doable.

Specifically I'm hoping to use the `pattern replace char filter` to remove unit numbers from a street address before they are run through a custom analyzer (i.e. *#205 - 1260 Broadway* becomes *1260 Broadway*). Because of the custom analyzer, I believe I need to use this char filter to accomplish this.

My current configuration looks like this:

```
  elasticClient.CreateIndex("geocoding", c => c
            .Analysis(ad => ad
                .Analyzers(ab => ab
                    .Add("address-index", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Tokenizer = "whitespace",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "synonym" }
                    })
                    .Add("address-search", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Tokenizer = "whitespace",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" },
                        CharFilter = new List<string>() { "drop-unit" }
                    })
                )
                .CharFilters(cfb => cfb
                    .Add("drop-unit", new CharFilter()) //missing char filter here
                )
                .TokenFilters(tfb => tfb
                    .Add("synonym", new SynonymTokenFilter()
                    {
                        Expand = true,
                        SynonymsPath = "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    })
                )
             )
```

**UPDATE**:

As of May 2014, NEST now supports the `pattern replace char filter`: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/637

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the fluent settings during your index creation you can use the `Settings.Add` approach to add to the FluentDictionary in a more manual way, but with complete control over what settings are passed in. An example of this is shown in [Create Index](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/create-indices.html) of the [NEST Documentation](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/). I am using this approach for a very similar reason.

You configuration would look something similar to the following:

```
 elasticClient.CreateIndex("geocoding", c => c.
       .Settings(s => s.
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-index.type", "custom")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-index.tokenizer", "whitespace")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-index.filter.0", "lowercase")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-index.filter.1", "synonym")
           .Add("anaylsis.analyzer.address-search.type", "custom")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-search.tokenizer", "whitespace")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-search.filter.0", "lowercase")
           .Add("analysis.analyzer.address-search.char_filter.0", "drop-unit")
           .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop-unit.type", "mapping")
           .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop-unit.mappings.0", "<mapping1>")
           .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop-unit.mappings.1", "<mapping2>")
           ...
       )
  );
```

You will need to replace `<mapping1>` and `<mapping2>` above with your actual char_filter mappings that you want to use. Please note that I have not used a char_filter before, so the settings values may be a little off, but should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a follow-up to Paige's very helpful answer, it looks like you can combine the fluent and manual `Settings.Add` approaches. The following worked for me:

```
     elasticClient.CreateIndex("geocoding", c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_unit.type", "pattern_replace")
                .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_unit.pattern", @"#\d+\s-\s")
                .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_unit.replacement", "")
            )
            .Analysis(ad => ad
                .Analyzers(ab => ab
                    .Add("address_index", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        Tokenizer = "whitespace",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "synonym" }
                    })
                    .Add("address_search", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_unit" },
                        Tokenizer = "whitespace",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" }
                    })
                )
                .TokenFilters(tfb => tfb
                    .Add("synonym", new SynonymTokenFilter()
                    {
                        Expand = true,
                        SynonymsPath = "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    })
                )
             )
```

Comment: Nice! Glad to know these can be combined. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: how is this used in the actual query? i haven't seen a good example.

Answer (score 0):

```
       EsClient.CreateIndex("universal_de", c => c
         .NumberOfReplicas(1)
         .NumberOfShards(5)
         .Settings(s => s //just as an example
             .Add("merge.policy.merge_factor", "10")
             .Add("search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.warn", "1s")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_chars.type", "pattern_replace")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_chars.pattern", @"[^0-9]")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_chars.replacement", "")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_specChars.type", "pattern_replace")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_specChars.pattern", @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]")
             .Add("analysis.char_filter.drop_specChars.replacement", "")
         )
         .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
            .Analyzers(bases => bases
                .Add("folded_word", new CustomAnalyzer() 
                {
                    Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "trim" },
                    Tokenizer = "standard"
                }
                )
                .Add("trimmed_number", new CustomAnalyzer()
                {
                    CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_chars" },
                    Tokenizer = "standard",
                    Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" }
                })
                .Add("trimmed_specChars", new CustomAnalyzer()
                {
                    CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_specChars" },
                    Tokenizer = "standard",
                    Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" }
                })
            )
         )
            .AddMapping<Business>(m => m
                //.MapFromAttributes()
                .Properties(props => props
                    .MultiField(mf => mf
                        .Name(t => t.DirectoryName)
                        .Fields(fs => fs
                            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.DirectoryName).Analyzer("standard"))
                            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.DirectoryName.Suffix("folded")).Analyzer("folded_word"))
                            )
                    )
                    .MultiField(mf => mf
                        .Name(t => t.Phone)
                        .Fields(fs => fs
                            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.Phone).Analyzer("trimmed_number"))
                            )
                    )
```

This is how you create the index and add the mapping.
Now to search i have something like this :

```
  var result = _Instance.Search<Business>(q => q
                .TrackScores(true)
                .Query(qq =>
                {
                    QueryContainer termQuery = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input.searchTerm))
                {
                    var toLowSearchTerm = input.searchTerm.ToLower();
                    termQuery |= qq.QueryString(qs => qs
                        .OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f
                            .Add("directoryName.folded", 5.0)
                         )
                         .Query(toLowSearchTerm));
                        termQuery |= qq.Fuzzy(fz => fz.OnField("directoryName.folded").Value(toLowSearchTerm).MaxExpansions(2));
                        termQuery |= qq.Term("phone", Regex.Replace(toLowSearchTerm, @"[^0-9]", ""));


                 }

                 return termQuery;
                })
                .Skip(input.skip)
                .Take(input.take)
            );
```

NEW: I managed to use the pattern replace in a better way like this :

```
    .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
        .Analyzers(bases => bases
            .Add("folded_word", new CustomAnalyzer()
            {
                Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "trim" },
                Tokenizer = "standard"
            }
            )
            .Add("trimmed_number", new CustomAnalyzer()
            {
                CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_chars" },
                Tokenizer = "standard",
                Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" }
            })
            .Add("trimmed_specChars", new CustomAnalyzer()
            {
                CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_specChars" },
                Tokenizer = "standard",
                Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase" }
            })
            .Add("autocomplete", new CustomAnalyzer()
            {
                Tokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer().Type,
                Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "trim", "engram" }
            }
            )
     )
     .TokenFilters(i => i
                 .Add("engram", new EdgeNGramTokenFilter
                     {
                         MinGram = 3,
                         MaxGram = 15
                     }
                 )
    )
    .CharFilters(cf => cf
                 .Add("drop_chars", new PatternReplaceCharFilter
                     {
                         Pattern = @"[^0-9]",
                         Replacement = ""
                     }
                 )
                 .Add("drop_specChars", new PatternReplaceCharFilter
                 {
                     Pattern = @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",
                     Replacement = ""
                 }
                 )
    )
    )
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: what part you don't understand ?

Comment: @AstroCB read the answer again. my answer is exactly what John needed !